# Can I travel and come back 2 days before my visa expires?

Tags: international-travel

I am residing in South Africa and holds "accompanying spouse permit".
I have already applied for extension of the permit before departure of my travel and planning to come back 2 days before the actual expiration date.
I assume my extension would not be done before my departure.
Will I be refused to enter at the border due to the fact only few days left in my current permit?

Comment: In the countries I'm familiar with, you can do this without being refused entry, but I do not know whether that would hold true in South Africa.

Answer (score 1):

So you are planning to overstay? Pretty bad idea unless I am misunderstanding your question.

However South Africa does not require a valid return ticket so you may be allowed in the country depending on the circomstances at the time but again if you are planning to overstay that is a terrible idea.

EDIT

Please read the comments seems things can be handled in ways I had no idea about I love learning

Comment: In every country I'm familiar with, someone who has filed an application to extend a residence permit or visa before its expiration can remain after its expiration.  Nobody is overstaying here.

Comment: @phoog really? I know in China they give you a special paper once you have applied, but I never saw that in other countries and never received one

Comment: In France that paper is called a récépissé.  In the US, the overstay is effectively forgiven retroactively when the application succeeds.  Most countries' bureaucracies are not capable of processing applications fast enough.

Comment: @phoog cool learn something new every day I love it

Comment: OP can also plan on 'staying' just two days, I have seen enough questions about that for other countries